How to render an object inside (through) another object specifically
I have a character which consists of separate objects for the arms, legs, and one big piece for the head and torso. the character is basically pure white, with some principled bsdf mixed in for some shadows.The character has an object inside it's chest (literally inside the mesh), and I'd like that to be visible through the torso mesh but not through the arms. I tried flipping the normals and turning on backface culling, but because of the shadows it looks inconsistent. render layers don't seem to be an option because I'd like to rig several instances of this character and have them interact so the object inside the chest of one instance shouldn't be rendered over every other instances chest, just it's own. the effect looks okay if I make the character pure white with no shadows, but ideally I could keep the shadows and somehow make the torso transparent to just the internal object and nothing else or make the internal object always in front.
pictures:
current:

flipped normals and backface culling:

kind of what i'd like to achieve:


Hello, what shadow exactly makes it inconsistent?

@moonboots the since i've flipped the normals and turned off backface culling, the shadows are coming from the faces on the other side of my character's body. when the camera or character moves, the shadows make it obvious that they are being cast on the back side and not the front.

Could you please share your file? Remove the parts you don't want to share https://blend-exchange.com/
